# GSAP On scroll videos and text fade animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fade, gsap

Good day. I'm new to GSAP. I'm working on a project where I implemented GSAP to create a video fade with some text animation on mouse scroll. The logic of the animation is when we scroll the mouse wheel the video and the text change with a fade animation. The whole page is going to contain the same animated section two times. Each section is going to have 4 videos(so for 2 sections total of 8 videos) and the video will change after scrolling the mouse. Hope you got an idea about the animation. Check the actual animation that I'm looking for https://www.loom.com/share/0fca10c0f566413aa1e05f1ed8412acc

For the first section, the animation is working fine but when I am trying to create the second section which is almost similar to the first section I'm getting issues.

So please if anyone can give me some idea that how can I do it then I will be really very thankful. Also, you can inform me if I'm did anything wrong. Also please let me know if there any other better solution to do the same kind of animation. Thanks in advance.

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);


// Fade hero elements based in scroll position
// Show next panel by fade in
function header_videos(){
  async function show_next_hero_panel(newSection) {
    if (newSection !== currentSection) {
      //get text for animaiton
      let current_text = currentSection.querySelectorAll(".intro_video_text");
      gsap.from(current_text, {autoAlpha: 1, y:0, duration:1})
      gsap.to(current_text, {autoAlpha: 0, y:-100, duration:1})
      gsap.to(currentSection, {autoAlpha: 0, duration:1, delay:.4})


      let next_text = newSection.querySelectorAll(".intro_video_text");
      gsap.to(newSection, {autoAlpha: 1, duration:1, delay:.4})  
      gsap.from(next_text, {autoAlpha: 1, y:100, duration:1, delay:.4});
      gsap.to(next_text, {autoAlpha: 1, y:-0, duration:1, delay:.6});

      currentSection = newSection;
    }
  }

  const $hero_panel_el = ".main-wrapper__panel";
  const panels = gsap.utils.toArray($hero_panel_el);

  gsap.set(`${$hero_panel_el}:first-of-type`, {autoAlpha:1});
  gsap.set(".main-wrapper__panel-wrapper", {height: ($($hero_panel_el).innerHeight() * panels.length) + "px"});

  gsap.set(panels[0], {autoAlpha:1});
  let currentSection = panels[0];

  panels.forEach((panel, i) => {
    ScrollTrigger.create({
      start: () => (i - 0.3) * innerHeight,
      end: () => (i + 0.3) * innerHeight,
      onToggle: self => self.isActive && show_next_hero_panel(panel),
      // toggleClass: {targets: ".main-wrapper", className: "fixed-pos"}
    });
  });
}



// Verticall slide grid
//uncommon_experience sectoin gsap slide
function uncommo_experience() {

  let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".ue-card");
  gsap.to(sections, {
    xPercent: -50 * (sections.length - 1),
    ease: "none",
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: ".uncommon-experience",
      pin: true,
      start: "top +=98px",
      scrub: 1,
      snap: {
        snapTo: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
        duration: {min: 0.2, max: 0.3},
        delay: 0
      },
      // Base vertical scrolling on how wide the container is so it feels more natural.
      end: () => "+=" + (document.querySelector(".container").offsetWidth / 5)
    }
  });

}

header_videos();
uncommo_experience();
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo img {
  max-width:150px;
}
.full-sec{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
}
.bg-white{
  background: #fff;
}
.sec-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}

.header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 17px 0 15px;
}

.header:before {
  content: "";
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #D5D5D5;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.h-wrap{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.h-wrap .nav-toggle{
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
nav>ul>li{
  padding-left: 15px;
}
nav>ul>li>a{
  font-family: 'Mplantin-light', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

nav>ul>li:last-child a{
  color: #a7a7a7;
}

.h-wrap .footer-inner {
  display: none;
}



.video-wrapper,
.main-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}


.fixed-panel .video-bg-single,
.fixed-panel .main-wrapper__panel {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 10vh;
}


.video-bg-single,
.main-wrapper__panel {
  position: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  left: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding-bottom: 5vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}


.video-bg-single:first-child,
.main-wrapper__panel:first-child {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.intro_video_text h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PlantinMTPro-Regular';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.intro_video_text p {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2.38px;
  font-family: 'Univers-ultra-condensed';
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px 0 -5px 0px;
}

.main-wrapper__panel:first-child  .intro_video_text{
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-wrapper__panel:first-child  .intro_video_text h2 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-wrapper__panel:first-child .intro_video_text p {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 30px;
}


.wwd-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}


.wwd-wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: #d5d5d5;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  top: 40px;
}

.wwd-wrap-left{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 40px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 90vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wwd-wrap-left h4 {
  color: #303030;
  font-family: 'Univers-ultra-condensed';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.wwd-wrap-left p{
  color: #303030;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.wwd-wrap-right {
  padding: 50px 18px;
}

.teams{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 40px;
}
.teams div:last-child{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.single-team {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.single-team:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.single-team img{
  width: 100%;
}
.single-team h4 {
  font-family: 'PlantinMTPro-Regular';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.single-team p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1.15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.4/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vide/0.5.1/jquery.vide.min.js"></script>
<!--========================
        ===== sec 1 ====
        =========================-->
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="h-wrap">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="https://codeshaper.net/img/common/logo-black.png" alt="logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Nav1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


<!--========================
        ==== sec2 ====
        =========================-->     
<section class="main-wrapper fixed-panel">
  <div class="main-wrapper__panel-wrapper">
    <div class="main-wrapper__panel" data-vide-bg="https://projects.codeshaper.net/projects/essentialist/assets/video/cover-part1.mp4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro_video_text">
          <h2>The private members’ service for passionate travelers</h2>
          <p>We believe there is a difference between visiting a place and truly getting to know it</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper__panel" data-vide-bg="https://projects.codeshaper.net/projects/essentialist/assets/video/cover-part2.mp4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro_video_text">
          <p>Relaxation & Traditional Healing</p>
          <h2>Wellness Retreat in Kyoto</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper__panel" data-vide-bg="https://projects.codeshaper.net/projects/essentialist/assets/video/cover-part3.mp4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro_video_text">
          <p>Culture and History for the Whole Family</p>
          <h2>Family Trip to Morocco</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper__panel" data-vide-bg="https://projects.codeshaper.net/projects/essentialist/assets/video/cover-part4.mp4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro_video_text">
          <p>Adventure in a stunning coastal setting</p>
          <h2>Surf Camp in Cape Town</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>                        
  </div>
</section>


<!--=======================
        == sec 3 ==
        ========================-->  
<section class="what-we-do sec-padding bg-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sec-title">
      <h4>Heading</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
    </div><!-- what-we-do sec end -->
    <!-- wwd-wrap start-->
    <div class="wwd-wrap">
      <div class="wwd-wrap-left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 

      </div>                    
      <div class="wwd-wrap-right">
        <div class="teams">
          <div class="teams-left">
            <div class="single-team">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse

            </div>                            
            <div class="single-team">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse

            </div>                            
            <div class="single-team">

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
            </div>                            
          </div>             
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- wwd-wrap start-->
  </div>
</section>



<!--================================
        == sec 4 ==
        ==================================-->  
<section class="exceptional-service">
  <div class="bg-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sec-title">
        <h4>Heading</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div><!-- what-we-do sec end -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <div class="video-bg-single" data-vide-bg="https://projects.codeshaper.net/projects/essentialist/assets/video/itinerary-part1.mp4">
        <h1>timeline fade</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="video-bg-single" data-vide-bg="https://projects.codeshaper.net/projects/essentialist/assets/video/itinerary-part2.mp4">
        <h1>section 2 red</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="video-bg-single" data-vide-bg="https://projects.codeshaper.net/projects/essentialist/assets/video/itinerary-part3.mp4">
        <h1>section 3 orange</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="video-bg-single" data-vide-bg="https://projects.codeshaper.net/projects/essentialist/assets/video/itinerary-part4.mp4">
        <h1>section 4 purple</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<!--================================
         ==        sec 5      ==
        ==================================-->
<section class="full-sec">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey Alok. If you're trying to get the sections to snap instantly, [ScrollTrigger isn't built for that](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24423-how-to-snap-instantly-on-slight-scroll/) because it doesn't support scroll-jacking (purposefully). But you can create a similar effect [like this](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/rNOebyo).

Comment: Hey, @ZachSaucier thanks a lot for your reply. Honestly speaking I'm a beginner in this animation world. So it will be really very helpful to me if you can share some references or a better explanation on how to make scroll jacking animation similar to the reference video. Thanks a lot for the suggestion that you already given. Stay safe.